# Is it necessary to close browser in headless chrome mode?

Tags: selenium-chromedriver

I'm using Watir gem in Ruby and I was wondering whether if I do:

```
args = %w[--disable-extensions --headless window-size=1600,1200 --no-sandbox
                          --disable-gpu"]

options = {
              binary: ENV['GOOGLE_CHROME_BIN'],
              prefs: { password_manager_enable: false, credentials_enable_service: false },
              args:  args
          }

browser = Watir::Browser.new(:chrome, options: options)
```

(notice Headless mode)

I have to do `browser.close` at the end or not?

Comment: Unless you see a process sticking around you probably don't need to worry about it.

Comment: Great thanks. If you add some more back up info I can accept it as an answer.